# Pythagorean theorem problem

Tags: geometry

[image]

I'm trying to find the length of A in the diagram posted above but I'm not having much luck

if pythag theory is $a^2+b^2=c^2$
Then shouldn't it be
$$a+10.5^2=24.5^2$$
$$a+110.25=600.25$$
so
$$600.25-110.25=a$$
so $a=490$
Therefore is $A$ is 4.9 metres.

But, evidently I am incorrect.
What am I doing wrong and what is correct?

Answer (score 7):

You have the mistake in the first line, you forgot a squared sign: it's
$$a^2+10.5^2=24.5^2,$$
not $$a+10.5^2=24.5^2.$$

Therefore you get
$$a^2 = 490$$ 
$$a = \sqrt{490} \approx 22.14$$